# Emacs Haskell Mode 2.8.0 - where is it?

Tags: emacs, haskell

Where do I find haskell-mode-2.8 for emacs .tar? I cant find the download anymore...

Comment: You probably want to ask the maintainer. Something went wahooni-shaped it looks like. http://projects.haskell.org/pipermail/haskellmode-emacs/2010-July/000051.html is the announcement, and the site is AFK.

Comment: http://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/any/emacs-haskell-mode/ seems to mirror it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also get it from the [marmalade](http://marmalade.repo.org) package repository where it's called [haskell-mode](http://marmalade-repo.org/packages/haskell-mode).

You can also get the handy [ghc](http://marmalade-repo.org/packages/ghc) happy haskell mode package.

And, if you don't want to mess about with package managers - they are both available on Github as well:

- [haskell-mode on GitHub](https://github.com/pheaver/haskell-mode)
- [ghc-mod on GitHub](https://github.com/kazu-yamamoto/ghc-mod)

Comment: you can also look onto haskell-emacs (https://github.com/chrisdone/haskell-emacs) - it has many improvements over haskell-mode

Answer (score 3):

Seems that it was removed from the official repository. Anyway, you can download it from some package repository. For example: http://ftp.ucr.ac.cr/FreeBSD/ports/amd64/packages/elisp/haskell-mode-2.8.0.tbz (Note: haskell-mode is in pkg/share/emacs/sit-lisp/haskell-mode)

Comment: it's better to take haskell-mode from github account that specified in next answer. This version also contains some improvements, such as, support for hlint & haskell style scan...